# How do I get my dual binding to work properly with bootstrap datetime picker?

Tags: angularjs, binding, model, angularjs-scope, eonasdan-datetimepicker

For background, I am using [angular](https://angularjs.org/), along with [bootstrap datetime picker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

My problem appears to be that my angular binding is working in one direction, but not the other. Let me first provide some relevant sample code.

html

```
<!-- all of this falls under the scope of the angular controller I will show below -->

<!-- the actual date time picker -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="datetimepicker1"> Start </label>
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" ng-model="start"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- initializes the datetime picker using Jquery I am assuming -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>

<!-- submit button -->
<div class= "form-group form-group-sm">
    <button class= "btn btn-primary" ng-click= "submit">
        Submit
    </button>
</div>
```

javascript

```
// inside my relevant angular controller
alert('this works');  // this fires, so I know at least this much is hooked up

$scope.start = moment.subtract(7, 'days').toDate();

$scope.submit = function() {
    alert($scope.start);
}
```

Now that I have shown my relevant code, here is my issue. When I fire up my app, once the controller code runs, the input field for the datetime picker on the DOM is populated as I would expect. It takes the appropriate value of $scope.start, and all is wonderful.

However, the binding does NOT appear to work in the opposite direction. For example, when I change the date and then click my "submit" button, an alert pops up, but it displays the previous value of $scope.start

It appears that changing the field on the DOM did not change ng-model (or whatever the angular term is)

At some level, this makes sense. I suspect that there is another controller in play somehow... the ng-model inherits $scope.start from the parent scope, but when I try and change it, the change is not propogated to the parent scope?

However, I have not written any controllers to do anything like this, so I am a bit stumped.

I'll be happy to answer any follow up questions or post more code, but I  thought this was the most digestible I could present my issue.

Please someone help me with my scoping issue. I feel like this sort of issue comes up for me with angular from time to time, so an explanation would also be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you pls create a plunkr/codepen example?

Comment: Thanks @MattRowland, that got me in the right direction.